# SQL: Conditional where with mutually involving all variables

Tags: sql, aginity

How can I write a specific double or (multiple) where statement condition for an individual group involving conditions that should be included for all variables. Let me show you.

```
    select 
    case, group, department, riskscore 
    from sometable 
    where department in ('A', 'B')  -- condition that count for group A, B
or (group = 'one' and riskscore>5.5) -- condition count for one
or (group = 'two' and riskscore>8.0) - condition count for two
```

As you can see the program will select all group one+ 5.5> and two + 8.0> but i need them to involve the A, B department as well.

I know you can write it as follows but i wonder whether i can write it separately where I won't have to duplicate all the info that counts for both groups.

```
select 
        case, group, department, riskscore 
        from sometable 
        where (group in ('A', 'B') and group in ('one') and riskscore>5.5)
or (group in ('A', 'B') and group in ('two') and riskscore>8.0)
```

Comment: Both Case and Group are reserved words in MySQL

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please tag only the database product you are really using

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and particularly examples of what you do and do not want to select would all be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need logical `AND` between the condition:

```
department in ('A', 'B')
```

and the conditions:

```
(`group` = 'one' and riskscore>5.5) or (`group` = 'two' and riskscore>8.0)
```

like this:

```
where department in ('A', 'B')  
  and (     
           (`group` = 'one' and riskscore>5.5)
        or (`group` = 'two' and riskscore>8.0)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go for nested query (it may have performance issues depending on situations.
for example:

```
select required_columns 
from (
      SELECT required_columns 
      from some_table
      where department in ('A', 'B')
) Where (group = 'one' and riskscore>5.5) 
 or (group = 'two' and riskscore>8.0)
```